# Loading a page with drop-down box selected using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, drop-down-menu, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to manipulate drop-down boxes with BeautifulSoup (which I'm fairly new to) and I'm having trouble figuring it out. I want to scrape the data that is shown after the drop-down boxes are selected. Is there any way to load a page via BeautifulSoup with drop-downs already selected?
Here is the html of the first drop-down:

```
<select class="print--hide" id="Year" data-reactid="202">
    <option selected="" value="" data-reactid="203">Year</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
    <option value="2008">2008</option>
    <option value="2007">2007</option>
    <option value="2006">2006</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="1999">1999</option>
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
    <option value="1997">1997</option>
    <option value="1996">1996</option>
    <option value="1995">1995</option>
    <option value="1994">1994</option>
    <option value="1993">1993</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1989">1989</option>
    <option value="1988">1988</option>
    <option value="1987">1987</option>
    <option value="1986">1986</option>
    <option value="1985">1985</option>
    <option value="1984">1984</option>
    <option value="1983">1983</option>
    <option value="1982">1982</option>
    <option value="1981">1981</option>
    <option value="1967">1967</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: I was going to share the link, but it's blocked by a username and password, so I didn't think anyone would be able to get in. Here's the link anyway. https://mmr.manheim.com/?WT.svl=m_uni_hdr_buy&country=US&popup=true&source=man

Comment: could you give a test user/pass ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<select class="print--hide" id="Year" data-reactid="202">
    <option selected="" value="" data-reactid="203">Year</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2009">2009</option>
    <option value="2008">2008</option>
    <option value="2007">2007</option>
    <option value="2006">2006</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
    <option value="2003">2003</option>
    <option value="2002">2002</option>
    <option value="2001">2001</option>
    <option value="2000">2000</option>
    <option value="1999">1999</option>
    <option value="1998">1998</option>
    <option value="1997">1997</option>
    <option value="1996">1996</option>
    <option value="1995">1995</option>
    <option value="1994">1994</option>
    <option value="1993">1993</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1989">1989</option>
    <option value="1988">1988</option>
    <option value="1987">1987</option>
    <option value="1986">1986</option>
    <option value="1985">1985</option>
    <option value="1984">1984</option>
    <option value="1983">1983</option>
    <option value="1982">1982</option>
    <option value="1981">1981</option>
    <option value="1967">1967</option>
</select>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

items = soup.find('select', {'print--hide'}).text

print(items)
```

Output:

```
2020
2019
2018
2017
2016
2015
2014
2013
2012
2011
2010
2009
2008
2007
2006
2005
2004
2003
2002
2001
2000
1999
1998
1997
1996
1995
1994
1993
1992
1991
1990
1989
1988
1987
1986
1985
1984
1983
1982
1981
1967
```

Comment: I can read the html just fine. My problem is gathering the information on the website that is only shown after the drop-down menu information is selected. So, I need to find a way to select a value for the drop-downs through BeautifulSoup, if that's possible. I know with something like Selenium, it would be easy enough to select a drop-down menu and then read the information given, however, for my purposes I can't use Selenium. Can I pre-load a page with the drop-down I want already selected?

Comment: @Jacob you can set your choices from the drop-down and then check which Requests has been sent to the website via dev-tools and network-tab

Comment: I haven't really used the network tab before. Every time I enter a drop-down it says gateway/ with the address https://gapi-prod.aws.manheim.com/gateway/
How would I use this to enter values?

Comment: @Jacob i will need user/password to be able to help you. contact me on Skype if via `AhmedAmerican_` that url taken `POST` request with `cookies` and `headers`